# Loss of precision in GLSL fragment shader

Tags: opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0, glsl

I am now using opengl-es and I use the gl shading language. I hope to render to texture but I found a loss of precision. For example, when I write a float value of 0.5 to the texture, I found the actual value stored in the texture was approximately 0.498. What should I do to achieve higher precision?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably should consider storing your values (if just one value per pixel/texel) via packing-unpacking your values:

```
vec4 packFloat(const float value) {
    const vec4 bitSh = vec4(256.0 * 256.0 * 256.0, 256.0 * 256.0, 256.0, 1.0);
    const vec4 bitMsk = vec4(0.0, 1.0 / 256.0, 1.0 / 256.0, 1.0 / 256.0);
    vec4 res = fract(value * bitSh);
    res -= res.xxyz * bitMsk;
    return res;
}

float unpackFloat(const vec4 value) {
    const vec4 bitSh = vec4(1.0 / (256.0 * 256.0 * 256.0), 1.0 / (256.0 * 256.0), 1.0 / 256.0, 1.0);
    return (dot(value, bitSh));
}
```

This might be okay for storing values for something like depth-maps
And this would be kind of a 32 bit range for each pixel/texel

Comment: Thanks a lot! I think this method will help me and I will try to achieve higher precision in this way! Thank you!

Comment: @theWhiteLlama , Sorry for asking this . I am new to graphics calculations .Could you please explain this logic briefly ?. Why the use of 256 ? I am familiar with the masking and shifting using the bit operators , but not sure what this logic is doing . Why can we not use the 0.5 directly in the vector since the vector components are floats ?

Comment: @Chandan hey there! We don't use the vector directly in this case, since we are only interested in a single depth value that should have the most precision. We just use the vec4 component to make sure we can use a full 32 bit precision value for example our shadowmap

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the highp precision qualifier in front of your variables.

Comment: Thanks! That helped me with precision in shaders on iPad 8th iOS 14.4 (on simulator everything was ok). I added high precision for the whole shader but still precision was not ok. Adding highp before variables somehow forced it to be super precise! Thanks man!

Answer (score 1):

Render to a texture that uses more than 8 bits per component. If you don't have the [appropriate](http://www.khronos.org/registry/gles/extensions/OES/OES_texture_float.txt) OpenGL ES [extensions for that](http://www.khronos.org/registry/gles/extensions/EXT/EXT_color_buffer_half_float.txt), then generally there's not much you can do.

Comment: I will try to see how to use the extension, although it seems a little complecated. Thanks a lot for helping me!

Answer (score 1):

Even the next higher precision might not be enough, because the final stage of the rendering pipeline scales the pixel values to a range of 0..1, the end points inclusive. Thus 1 will be represented as 255, which suggest a factor of 1/255 instead of 1/256.

The same applies to all precisions: 0.5 can't be represented exactly.

Comment: I know the float will be scaled to a range of 0..1 but I am still a little confused. I had thought 0.5 is 128/256 and that it might be presented with a high precision.

Comment: In order of 0.5 to be presented exactly, the float value should be divided by 256; however there are only 256 8-bit integer values available, where 0 maps to 0.0 and 255 maps to 1.0. There isn't an integer value exactly at the middle (i.e. 127.5)

Comment: I see and I think I know what should I do now. Thanks a lot.